# How to get work done on a train, if I am easily distracted by others?

Tags: trains, tips-and-tricks, work

I am travelling often across Germany. I would love to use this time to work, especially because there is internet connection on board of the ICE trains. However, I often feel disturbed and cannot concentrate. I can point to 2 possible reason:

1. People are talking around, even if it is a quiet car;
2. I cannot focus because of the neighbors looking on my screen.

I have tried several strategies: i) select the least attractive seat; ii) use earphones and listen music; iii) make remarks to people when they are too loud. None of these really helps. I would like to ask if you have some tricks how to deal with such situations.

P.S.
1st class is not an option for me.

Comment: You are obviously easily distracted by your surroundings. You won't find working on a train easy until you learn to ignore what is going on around you.

Comment: Do you have active noise-cancelling earphones?

Comment: @NateEldredge I thought noise-cancelling is only useful on airplanes to reduce the white noise coming from the engines. For speech they are less effective (never tested on the train though).

Comment: Maybe you want to get a privacy filter for your screen? I'm not sure whether the angle is good enough so that a person sitting right next to you can't see what you're doing but you might give it a try.

Comment: They still have a substantial effect on speech and other sounds.  I would suggest trying it.

Comment: @Tom You are probably right, although I am not sure the problem is only on my side. I have very mixed experience of neighbors: from sitting quiet and reading a book to moving impatiently for the whole trip.

Comment: Unfortunately it is mostly just your side.  Your mind is picking up on everything around you, people talking, people sitting quietly, people walking, the trees and landscapes rushing past the windows, smells.  It is a sensory cacophony that you are not used to in your usual work environment.  But the more times you travel that way, the more accustomed you get to it and eventually you will be able to work same as your office.

Comment: There is (at least in theory) a "Ruhebereich" / "Quiet Zone" on ICEs where loud talking and making phone calls is discouraged. YMMV.

Comment: @Rama No, the problem is on your side. People who are behaving completely normally are distracting you so much that you've had to ask for help coping with it.

Comment: I feel that sitting in the quiet car, people will usually be more responsive if you ask them to be quiet. I mean in a normal car it's their good right to talk, but in the quiet car, there are signs everywhere stating that talking etc is not allowed. Usually, most of the times I ask people in the quiet car to be quiet, they will either be quiet or move away. Maybe you just have been unlucky? O

Comment: If I am recalling correctly, don't most ICE trains have on one side seats that are not paired? So this would stop 2 as you don;t have a neighbour. (Maybe I am confusing with RailJet, though)

Comment: @LyndonWhite Only in the 1st class

Comment: Train is that mode of transportation where you can not find silence because there are lots of different kind of people from different places are travelling...if I was at your place then I find a right place where noise is less and make sure that there will be some decent people who did not interfere at other's work and make disturbance..after that I exchange my seat with one of the passenger..

Comment: Step 1 - get a Tesla. Step 2 - enable the auto-pilot. Step 3 - enjoy working from your own car!

Comment: What language do you use? If you can use a language that neighbors don't understand, they may stop looking at your screen...

Comment: @Blaszard mostly English

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Active [**noise cancellation headphones**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise-cancelling_headphones), which contain a microphone and chip that listens to the noises around you and [acoustically cancels it out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_noise_control). I use Bose QC15, which  are good,but you still hear high frequencies (voices)
2. [**Privacy Filters**](https://www.ergonomicsnow.com.au/ergonomic-products/computer-filters/privacy-filters) for your screen, which block angled light making the screen appear black to anyone looking at it from an angle other than straight on, so the person next to  you doesn't see  anything.

N.B. 1st class isn't really better, but often even more crowded on some routes

Comment: Good answer, I hope you don't mind me adding explainations of the things you suggest for anyone who hasn't come across them before. P.s. in my experience I find noise cancelling headphones are better for lower pitch constant noise (like an airplane engine noise or the noise of the train itself), maybe low-tech ["noise isolating" headphones](https://www.cnet.com/news/noise-canceling-vs-noise-isolating-headphones-whats-the-difference/) like in-ear buds are better for sporadic noise like distracting conversations?

Answer (score 2):

> It is a common thing that when sitting free, people will look around and observe things. Don't worry, they are not spying on you.

To solve this probelm, I recommend you to **Occupy a window seat and turn the laptop a littile towards the window side.** So, they can't see what you are doing.

To cancel noise, **using a earphone with heavy sound will cause damage to your ear. So don't go for it.**

To solve this problem, you should practice to avoid noise from surrounding. Personally I suggest you to practice YOGA to gain concentration.